# How to fix an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

I started learning JavaScript and as a part of a small project, I have an array of Date objects, and I am trying to search in it with binary search. I don't know why, but it became an infinite loop. 
I know the problem is in the first if (if mid < right), because it works when the content of the if stands alone. 
But if I put only the content, the function gets stuck when mid = right. 
I don't see what in the if makes it an infinite loop or how to fix it. 
I would greatly appreciate it if you could be of assistance.

**timeDiff is a function that returns which of the two dates are greater (later)

**EDIT**

I will try to describe the code better...
the function of the binary search receives an array of date objects (db = database), and one more date object (objDate), that the search should find. 
I want the search function to return if the  searched object is in the array (this is the true and false), and  what is the index of it (or the index it should be in, if it is not on the array) - this is why I return also the mid. 
I know it is not the best thing to return two values, but I need them two, so I put them in two variables when I call the function. 
I add here the function timeDiff (that receives two Date objects and returns which of them is greater (later)) and an example for running.

```
function timeDiff(objDate, currDate) {

  var _MS_PER_DAY = 86400000

  var day1 = Date.UTC(objDate.getFullYear(), objDate.getMonth(), objDate.getDate(), objDate.getHours(), objDate.getMinutes());
  var day2 = Date.UTC(currDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getMonth(), currDate.getDate(), currDate.getHours(), currDate.getMinutes());

  return (day1 - day2) / _MS_PER_DAY ;

function binarySearch(db, objDate){

  var left = 0, right = db.length ;

  while (left <= right){

    var mid = Math.trunc((left + right) / 2) ;
    if (mid != right) { 
    var currDate = new Date(db[mid].date) ; 
    }

    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) === 0){
      return true, mid ;
    }
    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) < 0){
      right = mid - 1  ;
    }
    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) > 0){
      left = mid + 1 ; 
    }
  }

  (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) > 0) ? mid-- : mid = mid ;

  return false, mid ;
}
```

a running example that should return "true, 0" (but actually does not finish the run) is:

```
var a = [{ "date": "2018-09-12", "appointments": [ { "subject": "Code review", "start": "09:00", "duration": 1.5 }, { "subject": "JavaScript objects", "start": "10:45", "duration": 2 } ] }] ;
var b = new Date(2018, 09, 12, 8, 0)
binarySearch(a, b)
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Like Ele suggested, please don't let us wonder what `db` or `objDate` are or if the issue comes from them. Post a MC&VE. Something we can *play* with.

Comment: A minimal and complete code will be welcomed.

Comment: What is `return true, mid` supposed to do?

Comment: Give us your data and we can write you a much better method of searching and array

Comment: Also, `return false, mid ;` Try to only return what's needed. If it's false, than `false`. If it's `mid`, than `mid`.

Comment: This `return false, mid` returns mid's value `->` comma operator.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow
Here is where you are running into an issue:

if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) > 0){
    left = mid + 1 ; 
}
Your while loops will continue to run until it reaches the condition, however your left variable is only incremented and modified in this IF statement, which has condition if it's never hit will never update or go up. So this is logical error you are encountering here.

Here is what you should do:

1) Update your question with more information

2) Do a sudo code of how you think this should work

3) We will help you

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and for the help! I edited my question and added more information and an example. thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does end, it only loops twice.

```js
function timeDiff(objDate, currDate) {

  var _MS_PER_DAY = 86400000

  var day1 = Date.UTC(objDate.getFullYear(), objDate.getMonth(), objDate.getDate(), objDate.getHours(), objDate.getMinutes());
  var day2 = Date.UTC(currDate.getFullYear(), currDate.getMonth(), currDate.getDate(), currDate.getHours(), currDate.getMinutes());

  return (day1 - day2) / _MS_PER_DAY ;
}

function binarySearch(db, objDate){

  var left = 0, right = db.length ;

  while (left <= right){

    var mid = Math.trunc((left + right) / 2) ;
    if (mid != right) { 
    var currDate = new Date(db[mid].date) ; 
    }

    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) === 0){
      return true, mid ;
    }
    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) < 0){
      right = mid - 1  ;
    }
    if (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) > 0){
      left = mid + 1 ; 
    }
    console.log('looping');
  }

  (timeDiff(objDate, currDate) > 0) ? mid-- : mid = mid ;

  return false, mid ;
}

var a = [{ "date": "2018-09-12", "appointments": [ { "subject": "Code review", "start": "09:00", "duration": 1.5 }, { "subject": "JavaScript objects", "start": "10:45", "duration": 2 } ] }] ;
var b = new Date(2018, 09, 12, 8, 0)
binarySearch(a, b)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the find method of array

```js
var a = [{ "date": "2018-09-12", "appointments": [ { "subject": "Code review", "start": "09:00", "duration": 1.5 }, { "subject": "JavaScript objects", "start": "10:45", "duration": 2 } ] }] ;
var b = new Date(2018, 09, 12, 8, 0)

console.log(a.find(item => item.date === `${b.getFullYear()}-${pad(b.getMonth())}-${pad(b.getDate())}`));

function pad(num) {
    return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try the find function. but I did not understand the pad function. What does it do?

Comment: It puts a 0 in front for numbers less than ten, if you search for 2018-9-12 instead of 2018-09-12 without the extra 0 you will not get a match.

Comment: return num < 10 ? '0' + num : num is short hand for if (num < 10) { return '0' + num; } else { return num; } look up the ternary operator